# Openldap Client Machine hangs when slapd daemon is stopped on Openldap Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ldap, openldap

First i will explain my architecture briefly

Openldap Server: Ubuntu 14.04 machine with openldap installed. I followed this article
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-a-basic-ldap-server-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps
I have added schema for sshpublickey for every posix account

OpenLDAP client: Ubuntu 14.04 with libpam-ldap nscd installed. Again i followed digital ocean link.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-client-computers-using-ldap-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

I changed sshd_config file on OpenLDAP client machine and provided AuthorizedKeysCommand /my/script which queries ldap server and gets sshkey and then i have a key based ssh authentication.

This is working fine so far. Also i have a ubuntu user which is a local user and is not managed by LDAP.

Now when i stop the slapd daemon on Openldap Server machine then 
my active ssh session as ubuntu user on client machine hangs(not able to restart any service or run basic commands like ls or cat). Even when i try to login into client machine as ubuntu user which is not managed by LDAP, it fails(it succeeds the authentication but fails to get enviornment variable and open an interactive session )

Excerpt from ssh -v ubuntu@IP

debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).

Authenticated to 54.200.221.217 ([54.200.221.217]:22).

debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]

debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com

debug1: Entering interactive session.

It stucks there and then timedout.

What is the reason behind this? Also is there any flaw with my architecture. I don't want password based ssh as it is prone to hacking.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you stopped `slapd`, of course, and the cure is not to do it. It should be running at all times.